# Javascript decimal reduction produces incorrect result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which will produce array value from currentTime of timer by clicking button. In this case this is the result:

```
var data_catch = ["0", "24.871604", "27.1788", "29.69", "29.100", "30.570661"];
```

And then I need to get duration between array value with rules "the next value will reduce by previous value" which leads me to use this way:

```
var data_duration = [];
for (var i = 1; i < data_catch.length; i++) {
    data_duration.push(data_catch[i]-data_catch[i-1]);
}
console.log(data_duration);
```

The value of `data_duration` should never be minus, because the timer always going ahead and the currentTime always have bigger value than previous currentTime. But in this case the result of data_duration is :

```
data_duration = [
  24.871604, 
  2.3071959999999976, 
  2.5112000000000023, 
  -0.5899999999999999, 
  1.4706609999999998
];
```

The result have one minus value because of this reduction `29.100 - 29.69`
Why this is happen and how to fix this? Please help me..

Comment: This is a simply math problem: do you really believe that 29.69 is smaller than 29.100?

Comment: actually I think the problem is how he generates the values in the array, because 29.69 - 29.100 > 0 doesn't imply broken float point

Comment: ya I read that already, but still don't know how to fix the problem..

Comment: the answer below solved this problem.. thank you gentelman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Math.abs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) to get the absolute value.Also mathematically  `29.69` is greater than 29.100

```js
var data_catch = ["0", "24.871604", "27.1788", "29.69", "29.100", "30.570661"];
var data_duration = [];
for (var i = 1; i < data_catch.length; i++) {
  data_duration.push(Math.abs(data_catch[i] - data_catch[i - 1]));
}

console.log(data_duration);
```

Comment: This is solved my problem. I don't know about this Math.abs() I will keep learning. Thank you very much...

Comment: this is not a good solution, you need to set the correct value to the data_catch when user click the button.

Comment: @Atmahadli the objective of the solution is to demonstrate the usage of `Math.abs()`. The problem does not describe any `button`. I am sorry if i have missed any requirement

Comment: sometimes some people didn't know the exact problem and ask wrong question. as i understand the problem here is why the data_catch array is decreased from 29.69 to 29.100?(note that it is from the user click from time to time) by using abs the result is abs(29.100-29.69)=0.59; I think the correct data is 29.069 so the correct result should be 29.100-29.069=0.031;